# socket.io chat not working

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Hei so this is my socket.io chat it's from the website example...
Why is this not working?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="chatOverlay">
         <div class="chatMessages"></div>
         <input type="text" id="sendMessage" placeholder="Enter Chat Message..." maxlength="80">
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('.chatOverlay').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#sendMessage').val());
        $('#sendMessage').val('');
        return false;

      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('.chatMessages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        console.log (msg);
              });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
    console.log('message: ' + msg);

  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Console Log:

```
listening on *:3000
a user connected
a user connected
```

Thx for the help i need the index like this to make it work can't change it.
Not sure why it's not working i think the message is not getting send.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error on both server and client side?

Comment: If you don't know if the message is sent start looking into the developer console. Also 'is not working' is an insufficient description of the problem.

Comment: No i don't get no error, and yeah i'm sorry but can't do more...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've made some mistakes copying the *Socket.io* chat example. First of all, you can't make a `submit` on a `<div>`. Only `<form>`s can be submitted. Secondly, move the `<div>` with messages out of the `<form>`, because they're unrelated with the information being submitted with your next message:

```
<body>
  <div class="chatMessages" />
  <form class="chatOverlay">
    <input type="text" id="sendMessage" placeholder="Enter Chat Message..." maxlength="80">
  </form>
...
```